# Divide Width of Element Between Child Divs With CSS

Tags: css, layout, semantic-markup

I have a varying number of inline-block divs that I want to collectively take up 100% of their parent.  Can this be done *without JavaScript*?  The only way I can think of is with a table but it's of course bad practice to use a table solely for layout purposes.

```
|----------------------|
|{  div 1  }{  div 2  }|
           or
|{div 1}{div  2}{div 3}|
|----------------------|
```

I have also tried `{ display:block; float:left; }` but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Do you want to do this without setting an explicit `width` in percent?

Comment: Yep - you want the display mode of table columns - but that doesn't mean you need to add a table to your HTML. See my answer...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `display:table-cell` on your inner divs to do this. For the browser to make the inner divs behave like table cells, it also needs two layers of containing elements: one to acts as the table, and another to act as the table-row.

For a structure like this:

```
   <div class="outer">
       <div class="middle">
          <div class="inner">Item 1</div> 
          <div class="inner">Item 2</div> 
          <div class="inner">Item 3</div> 
          <div class="inner">Item 4</div> 
       </div>
   </div>
```

Use this CSS:

```
div.outer {display:table;}
div.middle {display:table-row;}
div.inner {display:table-cell;}
```

A nice structure to use is a UL wrapped in a DIV: the DIV acts as a table, the UL as a row, and the LI's as table-cells.

This technique is not well supported in older browsers - for anything older than IE8, you're out of luck entirely.

Let me know if you need more sample code than that!

Comment: Thanks a lot Beejamin!  I sure didn't expect Fx 5.0 to behave like an 'older browser'.  While it doesn't split them evenly, it's close enough.  Btw, who cares if it doesn't work in IE? ;-)

Comment: @Fantabulum: Don't set any `width` on the `div`s with `display: table-cell`, and set `table-layout: fixed` on the `div` with `display: table`.

Comment: Can this work on `li` and `ul` as well? I have a menu that is a bulleted list, and I want the `li`s to take up the entire space divided by number of elements. I tried setting the `ul` to `display:table` and the `li` to `display: table-cell`, but that didn't work. Any workaround to keep it as bulleted list?

Comment: Yep, @Shimmy, you'll need to wrap the list in another element: The wrapper is `display:table;`, the ul is `display:table-row` and the li's are `display:table-cell`. I've edited my answer to make this clearer with current info.

Comment: @Beejamin, thanks. That worked. However, the `li`s are not divided evenly, their width depends on the text it contains, is there a way to have the width of the elements equal to each other? ([Here](http://goo.gl/OGDzO1) is the website)

Comment: Not cleanly as far as I know - the elements really do behave like table cells, which adapt to content, as you know. The only time you can guarantee table cells to have even widths is if they have the same content (or no content). Perhaps you can exploit absolute positioning inside each cell (to take the content out of layout flow), but then it becomes tricky to center content within each cell...

Comment: @Beejamin I guess I'll stick to javascript :(

Comment: Leaving the `div.middle` bit out works fine too. So a number of `div.inner {display:table-cell;}`'s as direct children of a `div.outer {display:table;}` has the exact same effect.

Comment: @Beejamin there doesn't seem to be a way to add margin between each cell? I tried transparent border but no dice when background images are involved.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can use the CSS rules `border-spacing: 1em 0.5em; border-collapse: separate;` to provide spacing between the cells. Or, wrap the cell content in a child element, and add margin or padding to that...

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer missed an important CSS property which is necessary to work:

> table-layout: fixed;

This is the correct answer:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="inner">Item 1</div> 
            <div class="inner">Item 2</div> 
            <div class="inner">Item 3</div> 
            <div class="inner">Item 4</div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.outer {display:table; table-layout: fixed;}
div.middle {display:table-row;}
div.inner {display:table-cell;}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can utilize css3 benefits here. I was also facing this issue now i have fixed that using below example code

```css
.parent-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.child-item {
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent-container">
  <li class="child-item">1</li>
  <li class="child-item">2</li>
  <li class="child-item">3</li>
  <li class="child-item">4</li>
  <li class="child-item">5</li>
  <li class="child-item">6</li>
  <li class="child-item">7</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks & Regards,
Lingeshram

Comment: Could you explain what, exactly, is actually necessary to make this work, instead of just putting some code down?

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to expound on @lingeshram's answer. Flexboxes have come so far that I think it's really the way to do it now. If you have to support old browsers, be sure to check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20flex/) first.

```css
.container {
  display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
}

.col {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.col2x {
  flex-grow: 2;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
Evenly split three children
<div class='container'>
  <span class='col'>Inner 1</span>
  <span class='col'>Inner 2</span>
  <span class='col'>Inner 3</span>
</div>

<br>
Evenly split two children
<div class='container'>
  <span class='col'>Inner 1</span>
  <span class='col'>Inner 2</span>
</div>

<br>
Split three children, but the middle is twice the size of the others
<div class='container'>
  <span class='col'>Inner 1</span>
  <span class='col2x'>Inner 2</span>
  <span class='col'>Inner 3</span>
</div>
```

Here is a pretty good [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to the different ways you can use flexbox.