# PHP Get all alike values from array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I've got an multidimensional array with some values.

```
[

    1 => [
        'label' => 'SEO',
        'content' => 'Some content',
        'group' => 'We can offer'
    ]

    2 => [
        'label' => 'Webdesign',
        'content' => 'Some content',
        'group' => 'We can offer'
    ]

    3 => [
        'label' => 'Contact',
        'content' => 'Some content',
        'group' => 'Who are we?'
    ]

    4 => [
        'label' => 'Logodesign',
        'content' => 'Some content',
        'group' => 'We can offer'
    ]

    5 => [
        'label' => 'Address',
        'content' => 'Some content',
        'group' => 'Who are we?'
    ]

]
```

The `group` element is a variety of user input. I want to sort all `group` elements what are the same into the same array. It's then going to be displayed. If there are only 2 elements with the same `group` value, then there will only be two columns (50% width on both) in a `.row` element in HTML, if there are 1 element, only one column (100% width). I'm trying to build a very simple CMS if anyone was wondering why. There may be more easier ways to do this, but I can't think of any.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I just got the array sorted i think. It looks right.

Now I just need to display it the right way.

```
$i = 0;
$count = count($data['sections']);
$content = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if (!in_array($data['sections'][$i]['group'], $content)) {
            $content[] = $data['sections'][$i]['group'];
        }

        $content[$data['sections'][$i]['group']][] = ['label' => $data['sections'][$i]['label'], 'content' => $data['sections'][$i]['content']];
    }
```

Comment: And if there are more than two elements? Do you want equal width for all elements so that if there are n elements they get 1/n:th of the space?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Example the content element will get the class `.c-#-12`

Comment: Then you might want to have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629951/divide-width-of-element-between-child-divs-with-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Group the array

Simply loop through the array and put all the elements into a new, nested array:

```
$content = array();

foreach($data['sections'] as $section) {
   $content[$section['group']][] = $section;
}
```

This gives you an array `$content` of this format:

```
[

    'We can offer' => [

            1 => [
                'label' => 'SEO',
                'content' => 'Some content',
                'group' => 'We can offer'
            ]

            2 => [
                'label' => 'Webdesign',
                'content' => 'Some content',
                'group' => 'We can offer'
            ]

            ...

    ]

    'Who are we?' => [

            ...

    ]

]
```

## Divide the width: Table display

So how do you output this so that every category gets equal width? First you need to loop through the nested array to print some HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <?php foreach($content as $group) { ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach($group as $item) { ?>
                <div class="item"><?php echo $item['content']; ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6630011/2200659) for one way to do it using CSS:

```
div.outer  { display:table; }
div.row    { display:table-row; }
div.item   { display:table-cell; }
```

## Divide the width: Explicit width

Another way to do it is to calculate the width in percentage in PHP and set it explicitly with the `width` attribute:

```
<?php foreach($content as $group) { ?>
    <div class="row">
    <?php $w = 100 / count($group); ?>
        <?php foreach($group as $item) { ?>
            <div class="item" width="<?php echo $w; ?>%">
                <?php echo $item['content']; ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That made much more sense than my for loop.
I understand it much better now. I have my own small grid system, so I will add classes (if 3 colums, c-4-12). Etc.
This helped me alot. Thank you!